# Sed Regular Expression with /P

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have the following SED regular expression on Linux and am wondering if "/P" means literally to match "/P"? (I'm new to SED but know Perl regular expressions) See below:

```
sed -e 's,\(.*\)/P.*$,\1,'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, literal `/P`. `,` are delimiters.

Comment: Yes.  It is deleting the last `/P` and everything that comes after it.  I would probably do `s/\/P.*$//` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "/P" is literally matching "/P".

's' is the sed subtitute command, in this case using ',' as a delimiter. See 'man sed'.